# How to connect SQL Database with List view?

Tags: sql, database, listview

i have just created a Database and i want to create a customviewlist, where in order to display the data of the database in a listview. How can i realize this ? I hope somebody can help me soon :)

Here is the code for my DatabaseHandler:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import java.util.List;

import android.content.ContentValues;

import android.content.Context;

import android.database.Cursor;

import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;

import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    // All Static variables

    // Database Version

    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 5;

    // Database Name

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "PositionManager";

    // Positions table name

    private static final String TABLE_POSITIONS = "positions";

    // Positions Table Columns names

    private static final String KEY_ID = "_id";

    private static final String KEY_NAME = "Name";

    private static final String KEY_KATEGORIE = "Kategorie";

    private static final String KEY_LAENGE = "Laenge";

    private static final String KEY_BREITE = "Breite";

    public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {

        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);

    }

    // Creating Tables

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        String CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_POSITIONS + "("

        + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_NAME + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_KATEGORIE + " TEXT," + KEY_LAENGE + " REAL," + KEY_BREITE
                + " REAL" + ")";

        db.execSQL(CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE);

    }

    // Upgrading database

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

        // Drop older table if existed

        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_POSITIONS);

        // Create tables again

        onCreate(db);

    }

    /**
     * 
     * All CRUD(Create, Read, Update, Delete) Operations
     */

    // Adding new contact

    void addPosition(Position position) {

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

        values.put(KEY_NAME, position.getName()); // Name

        values.put(KEY_KATEGORIE, position.getKategorie()); // Kategorie

        values.put(KEY_LAENGE, position.getLaenge()); // Länge

        values.put(KEY_BREITE, position.getBreite()); // Breite

        // Inserting Row

        db.insert(TABLE_POSITIONS, null, values);

        db.close(); // Closing database connection

    }

    // Getting single position

    Position getPosition(int id) {

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

        Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_POSITIONS, new String[] { KEY_ID,

        KEY_NAME, KEY_KATEGORIE, KEY_LAENGE, KEY_BREITE }, KEY_ID + "=?",

        new String[] { String.valueOf(id) }, null, null, null, null);

        if (cursor != null)

            cursor.moveToFirst();

        Position position = new Position(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)),
                cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2), cursor.getFloat(3),
                cursor.getFloat(4));

        // return position

        return position;

    }

    // Getting All Positions

    public List<Position> getAllPositions() {

        List<Position> positionList = new ArrayList<Position>();

        // Select All Query

        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_POSITIONS;

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        // looping through all rows and adding to list

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {

            do {

                Position position = new Position();

                position.setID(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));

                position.setName(cursor.getString(1));

                position.setKategorie(cursor.getString(2));

                position.setLaenge(cursor.getFloat(3));

                position.setBreite(cursor.getFloat(4));

                // Adding position to list

                positionList.add(position);

            } while (cursor.moveToNext());

        }

        // return position list

        return positionList;

    }

    // Updating single position

    public int updatePosition(Position position) {

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

        values.put(KEY_NAME, position.getName());

        values.put(KEY_KATEGORIE, position.getKategorie());

        values.put(KEY_LAENGE, position.getLaenge());

        values.put(KEY_BREITE, position.getBreite());

        // updating row

        return db.update(TABLE_POSITIONS, values, KEY_ID + " = ?",

        new String[] { String.valueOf(position.getID()) });

    }

    // Deleting single position

    public void deletePosition(Position position) {

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        db.delete(TABLE_POSITIONS, KEY_ID + " = ?",

        new String[] { String.valueOf(position.getID()) });

        db.close();

    }

    // Getting positions Count

    public int getPositionsCount() {

        String countQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_POSITIONS;

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);

        int resultCount = cursor.getCount();

        cursor.close();

        // return count

        return resultCount;

    }


    }
```

Here is the Code for my AndroidSQLLiteTutorialActivity

```
import java.util.List;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;


public class AndroidSQLiteTutorialActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(this);

        /**
         * CRUD Operations
         * */
        // Inserting Positions
        Log.d("Insert: ", "Inserting ..");
        db.addPosition(new Position("Hobbersdorfer Felder", "Landschaft" , 53.94966, 10.70343));
        db.addPosition(new Position("Felder bei Pelzerhaken", "Landschaft", 54.10039, 10.83878));
        db.addPosition(new Position("Felder bei Neustadt", "Landschaft" , 54.10713, 10.84201));
        db.addPosition(new Position("Felder bei Gronenberg", "Landschaft" , 54.04454, 10.69646));
        db.addPosition(new Position("Felder bei Stolpe", "Landschaft" , 54.15785, 10.78290));
        db.addPosition(new Position("Felder bei Ruhleben", "Landschaft" , 54.11740, 10.88896));
        db.addPosition(new Position("Niendorfer Hafen: ", "Häfen" , 53.99321, 10.81323));
        db.addPosition(new Position("Neustädter Hafen: ", "Häfen" , 54.10509, 10.81117));


        // Reading all positions
        Log.d("Reading: ", "Reading all positions..");
        List<Position> positions = db.getAllPositions();       

        for (Position cn : positions) {
            String log = "Id: "+cn.getID()+" ,Name: " + cn.getName() +" ,Kategorie: " + cn.getKategorie() + " ,Länge: " + cn.getLaenge()+" ,Breite: " + cn.getBreite();
                // Writing Contacts to log
        Log.d("Name: ", log);

        }
    }
}
```

And finally this is the code for my List view:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:divider="#b5b5b5"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector" >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Asking "how can I do this" is a bit too broad here. Break down your problem.

Comment: well, i have no idea how to display the data from my database into a list view, that is my problem

Answer (score 0):

Use adapter, custom or standard. Try `ArrayAdapter` [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html), it's easy to use. Here's my code from one University work, hope it helps.

```
private List<Map<String,Object>> mUserList = new ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>();
private Map<String,Object> mMap;

private DBSelectQueries selectQueries = new DBSelectQueries(this);
private Cursor mCursor;
private ListView mListView;

private void showUserDisciplines(int id) {
    //findUserDisciplines(int) returns cursor with query from SQLite
    mCursor = selectQueries.findUserDisciplines(id);
    mCursor.moveToFirst();
    while(mCursor.moveToNext()) {
        mMap = new HashMap<>();
        mMap.put(NAME, mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex("name")));
        mMap.put(TEACHER, mCursor.getInt(mCursor.getColumnIndex("teacher"))==1?"Teacher":"User");

        mUserList.add(mMap);
    }

    mAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, mUserList, R.layout.user_discipline_item,
        new  String[]{ NAME, TEACHER }, new int[]{R.id.discipline_name, R.id.role});
    mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
}
```

Comment: thanks, but still haven't got any idea how the code must be changed in order to work together with my database :/

Comment: https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Using-an-ArrayAdapter-with-ListView  try this